# how can i open a new chromium tab in mobile view directly from the terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

i am using **debian 11 on raspberry pi 400**. It can simply be done by opening the inspect element panel and clicking on the toggle device toolbar button. But how can i do it just by a simple command in the terminal? So that the

1. `chromium-browser --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0" "https://example.com/"`
2. `chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=0.75 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel 2 Build/PQ3A.190805.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Mobile Safari/537.36" "https://example.com/"`

tried the above commands, but no change.(normal desktop view)